# Need USB C cable / connector insulation voltage....and ESD on shield, will impact the internal signals

Tags: safety, esd, usb-c, insulation, hipot

Any one know how much voltage the standard USB C cable insulation can withstand?..Also want to know shield to internal conductor insulation..If I apply ESD on the connector shield, will it impact the internal signals?

Answer (score 1):

Specs require that dielectric strenghth of a mated connector pair shall withstand 100 VAC without breakdown.

Armed with that, you can't determine anything else from an officially approved cable that is mated or unmated. It is allowed to withstand more but it is also allowed to withstand less when unmated.

And cables you have bought might not be officially approved. So unapproved cables don't have to withstand any amount or work at all, because they cannot be called USB cables.